# Using VirtualPathProvider for simple static files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

We are using custom VirtualPathProvider to serve files from ASP.NET-based web site. To serve static files, like images, css and scripts, we explicitly stated that StaticFileHandler should be used for files with this extension. Like this:

```
<add verb="GET" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"></add>
```

All of this seems logical and works except one fact - all virtual files served with this handler are coming to client with **"Cache-Control: private"** header. This is not what I would expect for static file.

**Is there any good way to make those files cacheable?**

Additional info:

1. Yes, it's possible to add cache header in a simple HttpModule that would add it for all ".js" files, but this is not good way.
2. I've found [this post](http://nathanaeljones.com/11081_Using_a_custom_VirtualPathProvider_can_cause_OutOfMemoryExceptions), that seems related to our problem. It refers to [KB947461](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/947461#appliesto). But it's not clear, is this patch still not applied to the framework? Almost a year passed. And where to get it, if not.

**Update**:
Looks like patch from [KB947461](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/947461#appliesto) is included in .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. And we already have it installed.

**Update 2**: 
For now we've ended up with this HttpModule that add cache headers if current handler is StaticFileHandler. But this is definitely a crutch.

Comment: Any luck  implementing this?!

Comment: You dont need a custom module/handler for that purpose. [See my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714490/staticfilehandler-that-supports-caching-of-virtualpathprovider-served-content/37055207#37055207)

Comment: I should say this is very hacky approach. On every call to "Open" method you reach to the globally available current HttpResponse and modify its cache headers. While this will work it is much worse solution than custom handler.

Answer (score 2):

Unbelievable that the built in one doesn't do it. This looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/talifun-web/wiki/StaticFileHandler

Comment: Did you ever get this working with your embedded virtual path provider? I am trying as the Datatables JS is a few 100kb each time without caching

Comment: nope, still on the TODO list unfortunately. Probably easiest to include the js file directly, or use RequestReduce.

Comment: Yeah I followed the setup and it seemed to serve normal js files but not the ones for data tables.  When switch back it works without caching. Thought about just including or maybe a basic module to add cache resources from dll for week etc.

Comment: (assuming we are talking about Mvc.Jquery.Datatables here) If you install the .Templates project it should put the correct JS into your project. If you DONT install the VPP, then the default StaticFileHandler should work with those files. If you raise an issue on github, we can discuss this further

Answer (score 0):

Try Active Cache in IIS, WebSite properties and Cache Tab. In my case works very well.